# Problema con rutas POST / GET

Tags: laravel-5

Estaba haciendo pruebas con rutas en ***Larevel 5.1***, en local, y me he encontrado con un ¿posible error de diseño del Framework?

Si creo una ruta como ésta (teniendo en el controlador correspondiente el método indicado):

```
Route::post(
    'test/rooting',         
    'TestController@rooting'
);
```

tengo que añadir la siguiente:

```
Route::get(
    'test/rooting',         
    function () {

        return view( 'errors/404' );
});
```

Así no hay problemas, si se hace la petición GET, se carga la pagina 404, pero si no se añade esta ruta de tipo GET, lo que ocurre es que aparece el típico mensaje:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Esto también ocurre si se hace algo más sencillo como:

```
Route::post( 
    'test/rooting2', 
    function () {

        return "bar";
});
```

No sólo si la petición se dirige a un controlador...

Y lo curioso es que no se genera ningún log de error. Yo creo que el comportamiento por defecto debería ser redirigir automáticamente al 404. Estuve unos minutos desconcertado hasta que vi que era una ruta de tipo POST...

No se si esto está documentado en alguna parte, puede que en anteriores versiones, o es, como mencione, algún tipo de error. ¿Alguien ha observado esto? ¿hay algún motivo intencionado detrás? ¿Se cambió en versiones posteriores?

***Editada:*** 
Añado las rutas POST en la clase ***VerifyCsrfToken*** en la propiedad $except, para poder probar sin errores de CSRF. Hago las pruebas con Chrome / Postman.
Con debug a **true** la petición GET muestra el error:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

```
> 1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218: in
> RouteCollection.php line 218 at
> RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in
> RouteCollection.php line 205 at
> RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in
> RouteCollection.php line 158 at
> RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 750 at
> Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 659 at
> Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635 at
> Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236 at
> Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) at
> call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
> 139 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in
> Debugbar.php line 51 at Debugbar->handle(object(Request),
> object(Closure)) at call_user_func_array(array(object(Debugbar),
> 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
> line 124 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
> in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50 at
> VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
> call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'),
> array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in
> ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49 at
> ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
> call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'),
> array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in
> StartSession.php line 62 at StartSession->handle(object(Request),
> object(Closure)) at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession),
> 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
> line 124 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
> in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37 at
> AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
> at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse),
> 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
> line 124 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
> in EncryptCookies.php line 59 at
> EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
> call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'),
> array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in
> CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44 at
> CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
> call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'),
> array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) at
> call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
> 102 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122 at
> Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line
> 87 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Answer (score 1):

Para manejar la excepción `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` debes primero crear un archivo en `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`.

Luego debes modificar el método `render` del archivo **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```php
// Agregar esto a la cabecera
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;

// Manejar la excepción
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        return abort('404');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Tengo el fichero que mencionas y he averiguado que para el caso, tengo que crear una ruta GET al mismo, explícitamente. Lo que me interesa es si, esto es así por algún motivo concreto, se cambia posteriormente, etc.

Comment: No es necesario crear ninguna ruta para ese archivo.

Comment: Pues no carga automáticamente si se hace una petición de tipo GET y no está definida la ruta, en el caso de que la ruta esté definida para POST, salta el error que mencione, ese es a mi entender el problema.

Comment: He creado un proyecto en Laravel 5.1 con el comando `composer create-project laravel/laravel foo 5.1`. Luego, accediendo a una ruta inexistente me lanza la excepción que mencionas. Tan solo con crear el archivo `404.blade.php` bajo la ruta `resources/view/errors`, me despliega la vista mencionada.

Comment: volví a probar, siguiendo tus pasos, no sea que algo se me escapará. El 404 lo cree abriendo el fichero 503 que trae Laravel y "Guardando como...", sigo teniendo los mismos resultados. Si accedo a una ruta que definí para POST, mediante GET, no redirige automáticamente a la 404.

Comment: @Orici, creo que deberías manejar la excepción `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`, he modificado mi respuesta mi principal para ver si te sirve.

Comment: la solución que me aportas produce un error: "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161" en rutas GET inexistentes y un error: "NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 879" en rutas GET inexistentes cuando existe la misma ruta de tipo POST.

Comment: La excepción `NotFoundHttpException` justamente lo solucionás con el archivo `404.blade.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Siento desilusionarte, pero es un error tuyo en muchos sitios.

Primero, no te tira mensaje porque el `config/app` > `debug` lo tienes a `false`.
Y segundo, es una ruta tipo `POST`, por lo que no puedes acceder con una simple url, tienes que crear un formulario y añadirle el csrf_token.

```
<form action="/test/rooting2" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
    <button>ENVIAR</button>
</form>
```

Comment: En **config/app.php** la tengo en TRUE, en el **.env** en false, parece que prevalece la segunda. Lo otro ya lo se. Lo que me mosquea es que no se genere ningún log. PD: con *APP_DEBUG=true* en **.env** el trazado de error aparece en la página.

Comment: `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),` => el segundo valor es el que pone por defecto si no lo encuentra en el` .env`, no es el valor asignado

Comment: Ok, sí he visto que *prevalece* el del fichero .env